# For loop writes only one letter into a range of cells using xlsxwriter

Tags: python

I am working on a project to conjugate all the verbs into a single excel file.

I am using this sample website for reference: https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-machen.html

When I run this code:

```
blueBox = soup.find_all('div', class_='blue-box-wrap')

for i in blueBox[0].find_all('i', class_='verbtxt'):
    print(i.text)
```

It prints:

```
mache
machst
macht
machen
macht
machen
```

But when I run this code in order to write into excel file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter
import requests

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Python/Verben/verben.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

html_doc = open('Python/Verben/machen_konjugation.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

blueBox = soup.find_all('div', class_='blue-box-wrap')

for i in blueBox[0].find_all('i', class_='verbtxt'):
    for col_num, data in enumerate(i.text):
        worksheet.write(1, col_num, data)

workbook.close()
```

The excel file looks like this:

```
m
a
c
h
e
n
```

Basically every cell has one letter from the first iteration. I can solve this by first writing the loop into a list than write the list into the range of cells, but is there a cleaner solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, every cell has one letter from the *last* iteration. Because the last iteration overwrites all. And you're iterating over each letter in the word with `enumerate(i.text)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace:

```py
for i in blueBox[0].find_all('i', class_='verbtxt'):
    for col_num, data in enumerate(i.text):
        worksheet.write(1, col_num, data)
```

with:

```py
for col_num, i in enumerate(blueBox[0].find_all('i', class_='verbtxt')):
    worksheet.write(1, col_num, i.text)
```

basically taking your *working* code, and replacing `print()` with `worksheet.write()` and grabbing `col_num` info from `enumerate()` on the sequence where you find the items to write.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped. Do you mind explaining this in detail since I have a hard time with enumerate()

Comment: Is there something specific you do not understand from the official doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate or the many other docs you can find online?

Comment: Damn, no need to be harsh tho. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry if you felt that way, I did not mean to be so. I was just genuinely asking whether I could focus on a more helpful answer.

Comment: @Anilo_92 https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20210830-why-emails-often-read-more-negative-than-they-actually-are

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) for data persistence. It is more flexible and allows you to save in various formats, such as cvs, json, etc. So just install:

```
pip install pandas
pip install openpyxl
```

Then past your code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-machen.html'
response = requests.get(url)
indicatives = ['Indikativ Präsens', 'Indikativ Präteritum', 'Indikativ Futur I']
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
results = {}
for indicative in indicatives:
    html = soup.find('div', {'mobile-title': indicative})
    results['Übersetzung im Kontext'] = [verb.getText() for verb in html.find_all('i', class_='graytxt')]
    results[indicative] = [verb.getText() for verb in html.find_all('i', class_='verbtxt')]
df = pd.DataFrame(results).set_index('Übersetzung im Kontext')
df.to_excel('Python/Verben/verben.xlsx')
```

And enjoy result:

[image: Complited exele]